# Relation between circular continuity and elementary continuity

Tags: geometry

I read somewhere that in minimal geometry(incidence, betweenness and congruence axioms) the circular continuity

> If a circle has one point inside and one point outside another circle, then the two circles intersect in two points.

implies the elementary continuity

> If one endpoint of a segment is inside a circle and the other endpoint is outside then the segment intersects the circle.

but that the *converse is not true*.

Could you provide a (preferably simple) model to support the last claim?

Comment: According to Beeson, Strommer has proven that elementary continuity implies circle-circle continuity (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.4399.pdf page 19 footnote 11)  without the parallel postulate.